os.system in python code crashes raspberry pi terminal?
I'm trying to use can bus on the raspberry pi and I'm using a waveshare dual can hat. the sample code give is this:
import os
import can

print("hello1")
os.system('sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 100000')
os.system('sudo ifconfig can0 up')

print("hello2")

can0 = can.interface.Bus(channel = 'can0', bustype = 'socketcan')# socketcan_native

msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x143, data=[0x94, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], extended_id=False)
msg = can0.recv(10.0)
print (msg)
if msg is None:
    print('Timeout occurred, no message.')

os.system('sudo ifconfig can0 down')

with exception of the edited data being sent and the hello check. But when I run the code it runs up to the first hello1 and nothing else. when I stop the process and test any command in the terminal of the raspberry pi it returns nothing. such as typing ifconfig and enter it just leaves a blank line with no error.
I also managed to establish an ssh connection via vs code, but since executing the code it doesn't allow me to connect and just repeatedly asks for my password.
Ive tried restarting the raspberry pi, adding a ssh file to the boot folder, running the code directly off the raspberry pi using vs code, running the command in the terminal.

Given the usage of sudo in your os.system commands, this is probably more of a privilege escalation/password thing than a python thing. try running your python program with sudo (as root), and drop the sudo's from your os.system callouts.

it hangs because sudo asks for password. You could configure sudo to work without password for ip and ifconfig.
